# Lazy loading exception with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to learn Spring Data JPA with Hibernate, **currently within a Java standalone project** (though later I'll use things within a Web Project), and I'm getting the exception:

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.dbprototype.domain.Crash.vehicles

And I'm not sure why.

```
@Entity(name = "STAGING.TEST_CRASH")
    public class Crash {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "C_TEST_CRASH_NUMBER")
    private int crashNum;

    @Column(name = "C_RECORD_NUMBER")
    private int recordNum;

    @Column(name = "C_TOTAL_UNITS")
    private int totalUnits;

    @Column(name = "C_TOTAL_INJURIES")
    private int totalInjured;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="crash")  // fails.
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles; 

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="crash", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)   // this works ok.
    private Metadata metaData;

    public void printCrash() {
        // prints Crash fields, vehicles, and metadata.
    }

    // getters & setters
}


@Entity(name = "STAGING.TEST_VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "V_TEST_VEHICLE_NUMBER")
    private int vehicleNum;

    //@Id
    @Column(name = "C_TEST_CRASH_NUMBER")
    private int crashNum;

    @Column(name = "C_RECORD_NUMBER")
    private int recordNum;

    @Column(name = "V_VEH_MAKE")
    private String vehicleMake;

    @Column(name = "V_VEH_MODEL")
    private String vehicleModel;

    @Column(name = "V_VEH_YEAR")
    private int year;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Crash crash;

    // getters & setters
}
```

My Service Layer is:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class CrashService {

private CrashDao crashDao;

public void setCrashDao(CrashDao dao) {
    crashDao = dao;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("you called CrashService!");
}

// DAO layer will need all 4 CRUD operations on each table.

// read one Crash
public Crash readCrash(int id) {
    return crashDao.findOne(1000);
}
```

And my DAO layer is just:

```
@Repository
public interface CrashDao extends CrudRepository<Crash, Integer>{ }
```

My spring.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd 
    ">

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dbprototype" />

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes e.g: @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.dbprototype.dao" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <!-- data source properties -->
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
</bean> 

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- Spring based scanning for @Entity classes -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.dbprototype.domain" />
</bean>  

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

I'm not understanding the correct way to do a @OneToMany, though from some tutorials, what I have is "correct".  Though if I change the @OneToMany to use EAGER loading instead of the default LAZY, I get a different exception:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "VEHICLES1_"."CRASH_C_TEST_CRASH_NUMBER": invalid identifier

Could someone help me understand what is going on, and how to do the OneToMany correctly?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Does that relation works in the other way? If you'd like to access the `Crash` from any `Vechicle`?

What's the join column  in the table of `Vechicle`? I think, you miss the `@JoinColumn` annotation in the class `Vechicle`.

See the JPA WikiBook about ManyToOnes: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne

Code:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "join_column_in_table_of_vechicle", reverseJoinColumn="C_TEST_CRASH_NUMBER")
private Crash crash;
```

If not, please provide the table structures, and turn on SQL-Logging, and provide the select, which causes the exception.

Comment: Sorry for late response.  The primary keys for Crash table are the crash_number and record_num.  In Vehicle table, it's only the vehicle_number.  Vehicle also has the crash_number & record_num, which are foreign keys (though in my simple DB, not strictly set as foreign keys).  One other question @Nagy : what the difference between JoinColumn and using the attribute "mappedBy" as I have?  When to use each one?  Thanks again!